# passing in R array to C function with "NA"

Tags: c, r, parameter-passing, dynamic-library

I work in R using C libraries. I need to pass to a C function an array with numbers between 1 and 10 but that could also be "NA". Then in C, depending on the value I need to set the output.
Here's a simplified code

```
heredyn.load("ranking.so")

fun <- function(ranking) {
  nrak <- length(ranking)
  out <- .C("ranking", as.integer(nrak), as.character(ranking), rr = as.integer(vector("integer",nrak)))
  out$rr
}

ranking <- sample(c(NA,seq(1,10)),10,replace=TRUE)
rr <- fun(ranking)
```

The C function could simply be such as

```
#include <R.h>

void ranking(int *nrak, char *ranking, int *rr) {
  int i ;

  for (i=0;i<*nrak;i++) {
    if (ranking[i] == 'NA')
      rr[i] = 1 ;
    else
      rr[i] = (int) strtol(&ranking[i],(char **)NULL,10) ;
  }
}
```

Due to the "NA" value I set ranking as character but maybe there's another way to do that, using integer and without replacing "NA" to 0 before calling the function?

(The code like this, gives me always an array of zeros...)

Comment: Do not cast a _null pointer constant_ as given with the `NULL` macro. General rule is not to use unnecessary casts.

Comment: ok. thank! but I don't think this overcomes the problem

Comment: A comment is not for an answer.

Comment: anyway, you mean I should simply do `(int) strtol(&rating[i],NULL,10)`?

Comment: Sure! Note that you make sure to use a C compiler. Trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler often results in trouble. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: Actually with both I got `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104586/discussion-between-stefano-and-olaf).

Comment: What you do here is just plain wrong.  There is **no reason whatsoever** to pass numbers as characters and then cast them by hand.  R is perfectly capable of *storing numbers as numbers* and has extensions for `NA` that cover integer, bool, ... beyond the IEEE standard of supporting floats for it.  I offered a saner solution below; but you (or someone else) chose to immediately downvote it.  I have therefore not much else to offer than a heartfelt _good luck_.  You'll need it.

Comment: I pass numbers as characters just to handle the NA as I don't know how to do it in C. I know that R can do it, but then in C, how can I make that check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test for whether the value is an NA using `R_NaInt`, like

```
#include <R.h>

void ranking_c(int *nrak, int *ranking, int *rr) {
  for (int i=0; i < *nrak; i++)
      rr[i] = R_NaInt == ranking[i] ? -1 : ranking[i];
}
```

Invoke from R by explicitly allowing NAs

```
> x = c(1:2, NA_integer_)
> .C("ranking_c", length(x), as.integer(x), integer(length(x)), NAOK=TRUE)[[3]]
[1]  1  2 -1
```

Alternatively, use R's `.Call()` interface. Each R object is represented as an S-expression. There are C-level functions to manipulate S-expressions, e.g., length `Rf_length()`, data access `INTEGER()`, and allocation `Rf_allocVector()` of different types of S-expressions such as INTSXP for integer vectors.

R memory management uses a garbage collector that can run on any call that allocates memory. It is therefore best practice to `PROTECT()` any R allocation while in scope.

Your function will accept 0 or more S-expressions as input, and return a single S-expression; it might be implemented as

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Arith.h>

SEXP ranking_call(SEXP ranking)
{
    /* allocate space for result, PROTECTing from garbage collection */
    SEXP result = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, Rf_length(ranking)));

    /* assign result */
    for (int i = 0; i < Rf_length(ranking); ++i)
        INTEGER(result)[i] =
            R_NaInt == INTEGER(ranking)[i] ? -1 : INTEGER(ranking)[i];

    UNPROTECT(1);               /* no more need to protect */
    return result;
}
```

And invoked from R with `.Call("ranking_call", as.integer(ranking))`.

Using `.Call` is more efficient than `.C` in terms of speed and memory allocation (.C may copy atomic vectors on the way in), but the primary reason to use it is for the flexibility it offers in terms of working directly with R's data structures. This is especially important when the return values are more complicated than atomic vectors.

Comment: thanks a lot! I guess I first need to study a little more deeply commands, rules and nomenclature about dynamic C libraries in R. Btw, in terms of efficiency and memory consumption is this approach better than using `.C` function and avoid S-expressions?

Comment: Needless to say, Rcpp also a) uses `.Call()`, b) shields you from all the `PROTECT()` and `UNPROTECT()` line noise as it does all this for you behind the scenes, c) adds exception handling, d) gives you build tools, ....  But some people really prefer C and doing all the extra work and that is totally fine. As Camus said, we imagine Sisyphus as a happy person too...

Answer (score 6):

You are attempting to address a couple of delicate and non-trivial points, least of all how to compile code with R, and to test for non-finite values.

You asked for help with C. I would like to suggest C++ -- which you do not need to use in a complicated way.  Consider this short file with contains a function to process a vector along the lines you suggest (I just test for `NA` and then assign 42 as a marker for simplicit) or else square the value:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo(NumericVector x) {
    unsigned int n = x.size();
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (NumericVector::is_na(x[i]))
            x[i] = 42.0;
        else 
            x[i] = pow(x[i], 2);
    return x;
}


/*** R
foo( c(1, 3, NA, NaN, 6) )
*/
```

If I save this on my box as `/tmp/foo.cpp`, in order compile, link, load and even run the embedded R use example, I only need one line to call `sourceCpp()`:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/foo.cpp")

R> foo( c(1, 3, NA, NaN, 6))
[1]  1  9 42 42 36
R>
```

We can do the same with integers:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector bar(IntegerVector x) {
    unsigned int n = x.size();
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (IntegerVector::is_na(x[i]))
            x[i] = 42;
        else 
            x[i] = pow(x[i], 2);
        return x;
}
```

Comment: Always exquisite to get _immediate_ downvotes which _of course_ lack any comments.  Great stuff.

Comment: I actually didn't downvote you! how can I do! you give me a big help!! I'll try to study and understand it (maybe tomorrow, here it's almost midnight...). I'm sure it will help me not only for this issue! thanks a lot!

Comment: @dirk what's the rationale behind the preference to use Rcpp syntactic sugar `**Vector::is_na(x[i])` vs not using sugar `IntegerVector[i] == NA_INTEGER`? I tend to find that debugging is more complicated when using sugar.

Comment: If my math is correct, isn't suggesting "C++ --" the same as suggesting C?

Comment: Cannot argue with that, @JoshuaUlrich !  You see I _really am_ a caring C programmer inside...

Comment: @Alex does this NA_INTEGER really exist in C? I didn't find it

Comment: Do we have to separately implement identical logic for different vector types? Isn't there some C++ templating to save us from this?

Comment: But there are _different `SEXP` types_ under it all.  So I call this an R design issue.

Comment: We do have some code on the Rcpp Gallery where we switch inside but then you are forced to have `SEXP` in and out, which I personally find unappealing.

Comment: Moreover the interface to R is the C function `.Call()` so no templates for you and me when talking to R.